# Assertion error with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, junit4, assertion

```
Public class Person {
    private Skill[] skills;

    public Skill[] getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(Skill[] s) {
        if (s!= null) {
            skills = new Skill[s.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                skills[i] = s[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Assume there is a class `skill`. The problem is there is a test case in Junit that tests the method setSkill ugiving s = the skills array itself. This test case returns `Assertion error` telling me `The returned skill array should be the same` knowing that when I change the `getSkill` to be giving both arrays same reference the test case passes.

Can anyone help me with that please? how do I copy the elements not the reference? and why does the test case fails?

the test case is :

```
@Test(timeout = 1000) 
public void testGetSkills() { 
    instance.setSkills(skills); 
    assertSame("The returned skill array should be the same", instance.getSkills(), skills); 
}
```

Comment: can you please format your code better, and also post the test ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the error but why don't you just set skills = s instead of looping through the entire array?

Comment: @Pescis Or use `System.arrayCopy()` if you explicitly need a copy.

Comment: If you really want a copy, then use [System.arraycopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29). No need to reinvent the wheel. And you're missing a `}` in your code. And post the test code.

Comment: First, invert upper and lowercases for your class declaration : `public class Person`. `Public Class person` won't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that your test case uses `assertSame`. This looks for reference equality, and requires that `a == b`.

Your code creates a copy. A copy will never have reference equality to the original. In some classes that override the `Object` method `Equals` it may be true that `assertEquals` will pass. In the case of an array, try using `assertArrayEquals`.

For example this test should pass:

```
@Test
public void assertArrayEqualsTest() throws Exception {
  assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{1, 2, 3});
}
```

But this test will fail:

```
@Test
public void assertSameTest() throws Exception {
  assertSame(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{1, 2, 3});
}
```

You should be clear on why this is.

Comment: I got it now thank you so much ... I did not know that assert checks for reference that's why I had a problem in it. once again thank you :)

Comment: glad I could help :) the docs have a list of all the available types of assertion http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not copying the elements, you simply create another array pointing to the same elements. So if your test case later on modifies the array skills, you will also modify the original array s. I guess this is what causes the assertion to fail.

Comment: I do not want to give the the same reference. because later on array s can change which will change skills as well and I do not want thet to happen... and the JUnit test case is :   @Test(timeout = 1000)
 public void testGetSkills() {
  instance.setSkills(skills);
  assertSame("The returned skill array should be the same", instance.getSkills(), skills);
 }

Comment: You don't want to but that is what you are doing. Also maybe you should assert for equality instead of same-ness